# Dropdown list in line with and on top of text

Tags: css, list, positioning

I have text where one word is clickable and upon being clicked, a dropdown list of items should appear on top of the text (with the text staying in the same place).

I was thinking of using divs instead of an unordered list, because I feel like they are easier to position. However, I am open to all kinds of solutions.

HTML:

```
This is a sentence, with a 
<div class="dropdown-list">
    Clickable Word
    <div>List Item 1</div>
    <div>List Item 2</div>
    <div>List Item 3</div>
</div>. Plus some more text to fill the page.
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-list {
    display: inline-block;  
}
```

As you can see in the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hLyaf/8/ the divs height changes and extends the height of the whole line, instead of dropping down on top of the text.

Is there any way to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: The answer below is good however you can achieve this without extra markup by literally putting `position: absolute;` on your `dropdown-list` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use this tutorial i have made for you

http://jsfiddle.net/hLyaf/12/

```
body {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.dropdown-list {
    display: inline-block !important;
    background: #ccc;
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown-list div.drop {
    display: none;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! So simple, I didn't think of creating another div. Thank you so much!